# How to use <br> instead of <br /> in CKeditor

Tags: ckeditor

It's 2017 and it's the age of HTML5!  In HTML5, the line break is `<br>`, NOT `<br />`.  But for the life of it, I can't get CKeditor to ditch `<br />` in favor of `<br>`.

The incorrect `<br />`'s are giving me all sorts of problems.  Among them:

- Failed code validation
- (In Firefox) Using JavaScript's innerHTML on a code block that was created with `<br />`'s, returns `<br>`'s instead - which messes up comparisons about changes.

I found this old forum entry about the issue (in a related program, not in CKeditor itself):
http://ckeditor.com/forums/Support/are-not-validated-W3C-validator-How-change

But the suggested fix (changing `config.docType` in the config file) does NOT WORK!

I tried a bunch of different docTypes's, in both the top-level config.js and in core/config.js .

In **top-level config.js** , I tried:

`config.docType = '<!DOCTYPE html>';`

In **core/config.js**, I tried:
`docType: '<!DOCTYPE html>',`

But nothing works! :(

I also tried to hunt down instances of `<br />` in the multitudes of files, but didn't find any in the core part of CKeditor.  I presume that the `<br />` string gets created dynamically??

How can I get CKeditor to spit out `<br>` rather than `<br />` ?

Thanks!

Comment: easier to string replace the html output before storing into the database rather than updating ckeditor code --- or use something different like [froala](https://www.froala.com/wysiwyg-editor)

Comment: it hardly seems a big modification for CKeditor, lol!  
Are you suggesting that CKeditor is so unwieldy, clunky and poorly documented that it's basically useless as a code to tweak for such a simple matter?? :o  
Thanks for the suggestions about the alternate WYSIWYG HTML editors - though I'm hesitant to jump ship, unless something else is vastly superior to CKedit...  Opinions welcome!

Comment: and Froala requires a license... no bueno because I'm planning to release my project as open-source down the line...  I've been very impressed by CKedit so far.

Comment: Good luck in your search.  There are actually very few html5 standards capable editors.  You can forever dig through and hack the source - not impossible, but cumbersome.  Even CuteEdit works better (in XHTML content mode), but that costs money. InnovaStudio -- lots of hype, and I find you don't actually get what is advertised. Digging through them, froala is what stands out as ck'ish, but licensed.  But then again, you get what you pay for -- hopefully.  Perhaps troll ck's bug queue and nag why it isn't up to par with current w3c and for them to just make the "tweak for such a simple matter"

Answer (score 4):

Yay, it took some hardcore Googling (hard to phrase the search), but I found the answer!  I hope this will help others.

Simply add:

```
    CKEDITOR.on( 'instanceReady', function( ev ) {
        // Output self-closing tags the HTML5 way, like <br>
        ev.editor.dataProcessor.writer.selfClosingEnd = '>';
    });
```

What it does, from what I understand, is to wait for the core plugin *"HTML Output Writer"* to be loaded - and when it is, it modifies the "writer", which is a property of each editor instance.  The above way applies the change to all editors, but it could also be done to individual editor instances (though I find it hard to imagine why anyone would want to do the latter.)

For more info, from the CKEditor4 documentation:
[How Do I Output HTML Instead of XHTML Code Using CKEditor?](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_howtos_output)

All right, CKEditor rocks! :D