# django-ckeditor: Is there a django config/setting to get <br> instead of <br />?

Tags: django, ckeditor, django-ckeditor

I'd like to have `<br>` elements from CKEditor instances like that, not `<br />`. I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41496028/how-to-use-br-instead-of-br-in-ckeditor) with an answer, but I don't know where that code should go, in `config.js`? In my `<script>` element/JS file? And, actually, I want to know if I can use a config in `CKEDITOR_CONFIGS` to change this.

Example:

- I write the following in my browser:

```
This is the first line
This is the second line.
```

- I get this in the inspector:

```
<body class="cke_editable cke_editable_themed cke_contents_ltr cke_show_borders" spellcheck="false" contenteditable="true">
This is the first line
<br>
This is the second line.
<br type="_moz">
</body>
```

- I get this in my view when I process the POST request:

`'This is the first line<br />\r\nThis is the second line.'`

- When I save this to the database and then reload the page, I get in the browser:

```
This is the first line

This is the second line.
```

Because the `\r\n` was read as another newline and now I have two line breaks. (See edit below)

Why the `<br />`? Also, why do I get a newline after the `<br>` element in the HTML? This causes me to get `<br />\r\n` in my model instance attributes and thus, in my database. The `\r\n` won't actually cause a problem (see edit below), but it would be easier if I get rid of it; I think `<br>` should suffice.

**EDIT**

Actually, having the `\r\n` does cause a problem. When I submit the form, I get, as I said, `<br />\r\n` in my database. Then, when I render this in the browser, I get two linebreaks (`<br>`) because it read the first `<br />` and then the `\r\n` as another `<br>`. This happens because I am using the `linebreaksbr` template tag; my processing code outputs newlines in this way. It would be easier if I can get rid of the `\r\n` too, instead of changing my code.

Comment: Does it error if you don't have <br />? I've never known needing a close tag for <br> to be a requirement

Comment: Never mind I just checked the post you linked. That's really odd. Maybe just close the tag immediately? Or does that cause errors? Also <br> is the HTML breakpoint command and it doesn't actually use <br /> hence why it's immediately after <br>

Comment: Actually, my code would most likely give me errors and headaches if I work with the `<br />`. It's not really a closing tag; apparently, it's just the way CKEditor sends `<br>` elements in the requests. If I inspect the page in the browser, I see `<br>`, but I'm getting `<br />` in my view (not closing, it's `<br />` instead of `<br>`). Please see edit too. Having `\r\n` is causing me problems too.